# OutOfMemoryError - Breaking the heap size with bitmaps

Tags: android, android-memory

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryError exception thrown after a few loads of my apps main screen. The app loads data and a background image about a location. There are several options to choose from, and after 5-6 different location selections, the heap exceeds 192 MB and I get my error. I believe the issues is down to my using bitmaps poorly.

My code is quite long and unclear, so I'll give an example and hopefully someone can help me, as I think I'm failing to grasp the basics regarding image memory management (I have read documentation and searched extensively, I'm looking to ideally actually converse with someone about this).

---

I have an if with 5 conditions, each returns a different image.
I convert the image to a bitmap and set it as the new drawable source for my main layout.

Then I do this again, same function but for a different location, with a different image.

After a few times doing this, all these images being loaded seem to remain in the memory, and clog it up, leading to an error. Trying to keep it very simple, what steps should I be implementing between loading these different images into my layouts background to prevent this issue?

Comment: 192MB is far bigger than you'll get in a lot of phones. Typically you'll want to go down to ~32MB. Fortunately, those devices typically have less-dense screens so you don't have to shove as many pixels to the screen. This is a useful resource for handling bitmaps: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to recycle bitmaps, you are not using anymore. Make sure you are holding very limited number of Bitmap instances at the same time, and each time you finishing using a bitmap call its "recycle()" method.

You can find more information here: [Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) & [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Comment: Shouldnt dalvik take care of that when there are no references to that bitmap anymore?

Comment: But when should the recycle be called. And it's true that recycle isn't really necessary anymore. I've tried to set them all to null and even manually call GC on pause, resume etc of the activity, but there's no real change.

Comment: @Twentyonehundred, according to the information in the link above, explicit recycle call was required up to Android 2.3.3 (including), but is not necessary for later versions. May be they improved a garbage collection algorithm. As for recycle timing - it was recommended to call recycle as soon as possible, when you are not going to use that bitmap instance. See also here useful reading about bitmap caching: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Thanks for the info Densis. But if I just have, as per my example, one background with one bitmap loaded into it, overwriting each time, then when do I attempt to recycle the bitmap? As I am using the same function, with the same name and for all I can see overwriting it (though obviously it doesn't work that way). So after I've got my second bitmap in Bitmap mybitmap and updated the layouts background, how do I delete the bitmap that was created the first time?

Comment: @Twentyonehundred. What do you mean by overwriting? Are you creating new Bitmap class instance each time you load a background? If it is the case, then you need before creating new instance, to call "recycle()" for already existing instance. After doing this you can replace it with the newer one for new background.